# Flutter - Error when trying to Sign In with Google and FIrebase

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm getting this error when trying to sign in with Google with Firebase.

```
E/flutter ( 2822): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter ( 2822): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
E/flutter ( 2822): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:158
E/flutter ( 2822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2822): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:358
E/flutter ( 2822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2822): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:235
E/flutter ( 2822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2822): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2822):
```

I have followed all the steps (I believe) in integrating the app with Firebase, so does anyone know if this is a common error, and how would I go around fixing it?

If someone needs the code, I can provide it, but it is pretty much boilerplate Google Sign In code.

When I click the sign in button, it lets me choose Google account, but then it goes into infinite loading and throws this error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)` apiException:10 means it's most likely due to incorrect setup of SHA-1 or SHA-256. Since you said that it works at the office, but **when you change the device it was not work so make Update SHA-1 or SHA-256 in firebase same as your current device SHA key.**

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you change the laptop

1. install java
2. Add java path
3. generate SHA1 and SHA125 for the new device
4. Add to Firebase console
5. Download and add new google.json file from firebase to project folder
6. Run the app